# The Fubini-Study metric $ \omega_{ \mathrm{FS} } $ on the projective space $ \mathbb{P}^1 $

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds

I have a small question about the Fubini-Study metric $ \omega_{ \mathrm{FS} } $ on the projective space $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ appearing in page : $ 119 $  of Daniel Huybrechts's book intiteled : Complex Geometry. An introduction.

In this page of this book, the author says that the fact : $ \int_{ \mathbb{P}^{1} } \omega_{ \mathrm{FS } } = 1 $ implies that $ [ \omega_{ \mathrm{FS} } ] \in H^1 ( \mathbb{P}^1 , \mathbb{Z} ) = \mathbb{Z} $ is a generator. Could you explain to me clearly why do we have this fact ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why the integral of the fubini study form is 1? Or why that implies that it generates the integral cohomology?
Also the class of the fubini study form lives in the $H^2$

Comment: @A.Rod : Why that implies that it generates the integral cohomology?  :-)

Comment: By definition of the pairing homology, cohomology. If you integrate your form over a 2 simplex in the projective line, it gives you an element in the dual of $H_2$, which is generated by a triangulation of the line  (the fundamental class), a generator of $H^2$ maps this element to $\pm 1$, which is what the class of the FS form does e.g $<\omega_{FS}, [\mathbb{P}^1]>=\int_{\mathbb{P}^1} \omega_{FS}=1$

Comment: Thank you @A. Rod.  :-)