# Prove that Kahler form induced by Fubini-Study metric on $\Bbb{P}^n$ is the generator of the $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient cohomology

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I try to prove that the Kahler metric induced from the Fubini-Study metric on $\Bbb{P}^n$ is a generator of the cohomology $H^2(\Bbb{P}^n,\Bbb{Z})$

---

My attempt first by the Poincare duality we know that integral induce an isomorphic between $$H^2(X,\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}$$ while the integral $\int \omega_{\text{FS}} = 1$ it will be the generator for the $\Bbb{R}$ coefficient cohomology.

Secondly,I claim that $[\omega_{\text{FS}}] \in H^2(\Bbb{P}^n,\Bbb{Z})$ ,   since the image of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ under the first Chern class is $$c_1(\mathcal{O}(1)) = [\omega_{\text{FS}}]$$ it has to lie in $H^2(\Bbb{P}^n,\Bbb{Z}) \cong \Bbb{Z}$(which is torsion-free).

Is it possible to deduce that it's the generator of $H^2(\Bbb{P}^n,\Bbb{Z})$ without involving results from algebraic topology, only based on the observations above?

Comment: I'm lost here. You have computed the integral, so that gives an integral generator for $H^2(\Bbb P^1,\Bbb Z)$. When you talk about the generator of $H^2(\Bbb P^n,\Bbb Z)$, you're not worrying about the ring structure but only about $H^2$? But then naturality of $c_1$ should do it? What "results from algebraic topology" are you trying to avoid? Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you Professor @Ted Shifrin , I saw this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921491/360262 , in the comment Ahr used some algebraic topology to prove it.

Comment: In my post, I have the isomorphism $\text{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X,\Bbb{Z})$ , however I didn't show that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a generator of $\text{Pic}(X)$ (i know it's true, but I haven't prove it). After that we can show the image under the first Chern class is generator of $H^2(X,\Bbb{Z})$